# Attachinary : can I keep the original filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-upload, cloudinary

I use Attachinray with Cloudinary, for direct upload. Everything works very well, except the fact that when I try to save files in my controller, I do not have the original filenames.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
class User
  has_attachments :pictures
end
```

My form :

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.attachinary_file_field :pictures, as: :attachinary
  = f.submit t('.submit')
```

Once my files are uploaded, when I submit the form, I lost original filenames. Here is what I get for one file :

```
{"public_id"=>"ryfeummp2ikmzkss4cfy", "version"=>1427873505, "signature"=>"8475fccf9914dd05f6fg622ee39c1cb7ddd25f11", "width"=>78, "height"=>100, "format"=>"png", "resource_type"=>"image", "created_at"=>"2015-03-24T14:48:25Z", "tags"=>["development_env", "attachinary_tmp"], "bytes"=>19882, "type"=>"upload", "etag"=>"1fefdabba402263d18a92238ba4275c9", "url"=>"http://res.cloudinary.com/dd9blzv7x/image/upload/v1427873505/ryfeummp2ikmzkss4cfy.png", "secure_url"=>"https://res.cloudinary.com/dd9blzv7x/image/upload/v1427873505/ryfeummp2ikmzkss4cfy.png"}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to keep track of the original filename ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to have the original image's filename, you can use something like the following in your controller code:

```
params[:user][:pictures].each do |picture| 
  # Do whatever you need with picture.original_filename
end
```

If you need to store them in your DB, you'll probably need to `permit` it first and not access them directly.

Alternatively, you can tell Cloudinary to set the uploaded image's filename as the original filename:

```
f.attachinary_file_field :pictures, as: :attachinary, cloudinary: {use_filename: true}
```

Note that random characters are added in default. For more information:
http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520762-How-to-upload-images-while-keeping-their-original-filenames-

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried to pass use_filename as attachinary_file_field parameter, which was obviously not working. Now everything works perfectly !